# Attributes Inspector Not Displaying Navigation Item Attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I want to customize the title of the back bar button on a navigation controller using the attributes inspector in storyboards.  The following image illustrates what I expect to see in the attributes inspector when the navigation item is selected (taken from another post):

[image]

---

When I select my navigation controller my attributes inspector is empty:

[image]

---

I'm using Xcode 6 but also went back to 5.1 and had the same issue.  I opened another project and had no problem so I'm guessing that something I set (or the way I implemented the navigation bar) is disabling the attributes inspector for my navigation bar.

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your mouse pointer over the line that has "Navigation Item" in it (in the inspector), you will see the word "show" appear on the right side of the line -- click it (or anywhere on the line). You probably accidentally clicked on the row and hid it at some point.

Comment: Well, that was simple :-)  Another classic example of over complicating things.  Thanks for your help!